# What are the different meanings of 'fixture'?

Tags: java, php, testing, terminology, definition

I have some difficulty understanding the concept of "fixture". I know what a test suite is, a test case, a test run, 
but what exactly is a "fixture"? A parameterized test case?

It seems to me that the meaning or semantics of the term "fixture" can vary slightly by programming language or by testing framework? I think a *[phpunit fixture](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/fixtures.html)*

> "*the code to set the world up in a known state and then return it to
>   its original state when the test is complete. This known state is
>   called the fixture of the test.*"

is slightly different from a "[fitnesse fixture](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-fitnesse)", where

> "*Fixtures are a bridge between the Wiki pages and the System Under
>   Test (SUT), which is the actual system to test*".

Is there an expert in software testing around here who can answer this question?  References to other programming languages are welcome.

Comment: @chris (and knb) please put *answers* in as answers, not edits to the question.

Comment: glad you asked, i almost ask same question :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the context of testing tools you mentioned, such as *PHPUnit* and *Fitnesse*, this term definitely refers to the notion of **[test fixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/test_fixture)**:

> something used to **consistently test** some item, device, or piece of software...
>
> #### Software
>
> Test fixture refers to the fixed state used as a baseline for running tests in [software testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing). The purpose of a test fixture is to ensure that there is a well known and fixed environment in which tests are run so that results are repeatable. Some people call this the *test context*.
>
> Examples of fixtures:
>
> - Loading a database with a specific, known set of data
> - Erasing a hard disk and installing a known clean operating system installation
> - Copying a specific known set of files
> - Preparation of input data and set-up/creation of [fake or mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)...
>
> #### Use of fixtures
>
> Some advantages of *fixtures* include separation of the test initialization (and destruction) from the testing, reusing a known state for more than one test, and special assumption by the testing framework that the fixture set up works...

Comment: to summarize, a fixture is an object with a *known state* that tests (or whatever) can proceed with and have expected results.

Comment: so I'd say a fixture is some kind of abstraction of a test suite. Maybe I was confused because sometimes people use synonymously: the term *fixture* (the abstraction, or the stateful object at early test-runtime ) and *fixture configuration* (the configuration saved away to get processed by the setup() methods).

Comment: @davethieben Does it **have to be** an object? -- I don't think so, although it often is.

Answer (score 8):

Outside of the testing context, the term fixture is sometimes used to describe the initial data in storage (like the initial data in a database) when deploying an application for the first time.